# Trying to Pass String Array to another activity..Crashing

Tags: arrays, string, android-intent, android-activity

I am attempting to (upon the CALCULATE button being clicked) pull the contents (words/letters) from the editText and store them in an array that will continue to add to itself using the counters I have in place. I feel like I have the pass of the array from MainActivity to detailactivity fine but it crashes every time I try to get to the detailactivity in the usual manner. Here is the code.

**PULLING THE CONTENTS OF THE EDIT TEXT AND STORING IT IN THE NEXT ARRAY POSITION**

```
String explanationItem = expenseExplanation.getText().toString();
ExplanationDetailArray[placeCounterExplanation] = explanationItem;
placeCounterExplanation = placeCounterExplanation + 1;
```

**STORING/SENDING THE ARRAY TO THE NEXT ACTIVITY**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, detailactivity.class);
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle(); 
myBundle.putStringArray("explanations", ExplanationDetailArray);
intent.putExtras(myBundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

**RECEIVING FROM THE NEXT ACTIVITY**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
String[] testArray = myBundle.getStringArray("explanations");
```

LOG CAT ERROR

```
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652): Process: com.example.forecastspending, PID: 9652
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.forecastspending/com.example.forecastspending.detailactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at com.example.forecastspending.detailactivity.onCreate(detailactivity.java:66)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
08-26 18:30:07.894: E/AndroidRuntime(9652):     ... 11 more
```

Store Method:

```
    if (spotCounter == 0){
            editor.putInt("array_size", ExplanationDetailArray.length);
        for(int i=0;i<ExplanationDetailArray.length; i++)
            editor.putString("array_" + i, ExplanationDetailArray[i]);
            //spotCounter = spotCounter + 1;
        editor.commit();
    }

    editor.putInt("spotcounter" ,spotCounter);
    editor.commit();
```

Receive Method:

SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
             Editor editor = pref.edit();

```
        int spotCounter = pref.getInt("spotcounter", 0);

        if(spotCounter == 0){
            int size = pref.getInt("array_size", 0);
        ExplanationDetailArray = new String[size + 1];
          ExplanationDetailArray[0] = pref.getString("array_" + 0, null);
        }

        if(spotCounter > 0){
            int size = pref.getInt("array_size",  0);
            ExplanationDetailArray = new String[size + 1];
            ExplanationDetailArray[spotCounter] = pref.getString("array_" + spotCounter,  null);
        }

        spotCounter = spotCounter + 1;
        editor.putInt("spotcounter" ,spotCounter);
        editor.commit();
```

Comment: I am a little new and if possible would be very thankful for someone to directly answer this rather than paste another question's link becuase I have tried and tried and cant seem to figure out why it is crashing

Comment: what is the log cat error?? and have you defined your new activity in manifest?

Comment: I dont think its the activity, because yes i have defined it in the manifest and it works normally (the user clicks the listview Item), its only when I am passing and receiving the array that this occurs. and is there a way I can send you a picture, i dont see the option to include a picture(log cat error)

Comment: There is a ton of lines, more than what can fit in the comment seciton

Comment: You shouldn't post your log cat error in comment instead edit your question and paste it there. And select all comments and press (CONTROL+K)

Comment: In my code when it does this:Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, detailactivity.class);
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle(); 
myBundle.putStringArray("explanations", ExplanationDetailArray);
intent.putExtras(myBundle);
startActivity(intent);    **Is this starting the activity? Because The activity where this is being called is triggered by a different event. Or is this code just storing the values. Also there is one activity in between MainActivity and detailactiivty(receiving activity), is the code not suited for that?

Comment: So i guess to sum that up (is the code i have posted correct for just sending the array but not starting the next activity yet? Becuase the user has to click somewhere else to trigger the physical activity change? Maybe this is my issue?

Comment: What is on line 66 in detailActivity

Comment: I was able to get a lot, now my problem is with storing and receiving the array. I need it to take the new input (editText) and add that on to the end of the stored array (keeps growing) and then store it.

Comment: Heres what i have int spotCounter = pref.getInt("spotcounter", 0);
  //spotCounter = 0;
  if(spotCounter > 0){
   //editor.putInt("array_size", ExplanationDetailArray.length);
   editor.putInt("array_size", spotCounter);
   
       editor.putString("array_" + spotCounter, ExplanationDetailArray[spotCounter]);
    //spotCounter = spotCounter + 1;
   editor.commit();
  }

Comment: You can use chat of Stackoverflow itself but you need to collect 20 reputations at first :-) Please tell what you have on line 66 in detailActivity

Comment: well the error log is dated now, I am able to get the first array item to work but am having trouble adding on to it while storing/receiving. So no more crashing as mentioned earlier

Comment: Because the user will continue to add expenses on the MainActivity that will need added on to this array that gets stored. I will post my send and receive method as an edit at the bottom of my post above.

Comment: Ok, since we arent friends it said the message was stored in your other folder

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60205/discussion-on-question-by-user3924167-trying-to-pass-string-array-to-another-aci).